# Theorem proving from first principles using SML with HOL inference rules

Tags: sml, theorem-proving, hol

I am trying to prove the theorem **`[] |- p /\ q <=> q /\ p :thm`** using SML with HOL Inference Rules. Here's the SML code:

```
val thm1 = ASSUME ``p:bool /\ q:bool``;
val thm2 = ASSUME ``p:bool``;
val thm3 = ASSUME ``q:bool``;
val thm4 = CONJ thm2 thm3;
val thm5 = CONJ thm3 thm2;
val thm6 = DISCH ``(q:bool/\p:bool)`` thm4;
val thm7 = DISCH ``(p:bool/\q:bool)`` thm5;
val thm8 = IMP_ANTISYM_RULE thm6 thm7;
```

The result of the above code produces :

```
val thm8 =  [(p :bool), (q :bool)] |- (q :bool) /\ (p :bool) <=> p /\ q: thm
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your final theorem is that you still have `p` and `q` as assumptions, introduced via `thm2` and `thm3`, whereas you can and should obtain them from `thm1`.

The first theorem you need is something like `p /\ q ==> p`. I found the appropriate rule by skimming through the [description](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hol/files/hol/kananaskis-11/kananaskis-11-description.pdf/download) (sec. 2.3.24). It's called `CONJUNCT1`.

Using it, we can obtain `p` as a theorem from `thm1`:

```
val thmp = CONJUNCT1 thm1;
```

The same idea works to get `q` as a theorem from `thm1`:

```
val thmq = CONJUNCT2 thm1;
```

And then you can apply your idea for `thm5`:

```
val thm5 = CONJ thmq thmp;
```

The **important thing** here is that we do not use *`p` derived from `p`* (`thm2`) and *`q` derived from `q`* (`thm3`) but rather *`p` derived from `p /\ q`* and *`q` derived from `p /\ q`* (setting `show_assumes := true;` may help to see this more clearly).

Finally, we apply your idea for `thm7`:

```
val thm7 = DISCH ``p /\ q`` thm5;
```

to obtain the first half of the desired result, but with no extraneous assumptions.

The second half is obtained in a similar way:

```
val thm9 = ASSUME (``q /\ p``);
val thmp2 = CONJUNCT2 thm9;
val thmq2 = CONJUNCT1 thm9;
val thm6 =  DISCH ``q /\ p`` (CONJ thmp2 thmq2);
```

And then your idea for `thm8` works perfectly:

```
val thm8 = IMP_ANTISYM_RULE thm7 thm6;
```