# Exception on ACCEPT_TAC after THEN in HOL

Tags: sml, theorem-proving, hol

I am trying to create a theorem named "absorptionRule" by packaging the tactics that are used to prove the goal `!(p:bool) (q:bool). (p==>q) ==> p ==> p /\ q`.  However, I am getting an exception on ACCEPT_TAC.  When I execute each tactic one-by-one, everything works fine.

```
val absorptionRule =  
TAC_PROOF(  
([],``!(p:bool) (q:bool).(p ==> q) ==> p ==> p /\ q``),  
REPEAT STRIP_TAC THEN  
ACCEPT_TAC(ASSUME ``p:bool``) THEN  
RES_TAC);
```

Comment: It may be better to tag your questions with "theorem-proving", since the problem is not so much with SML as with logic and the HOL "library". It's a shame that there isn't a "hol" tag (I don't have enough reputation to create one).

Comment: @tbrk I've created the tag. Let me know if you want to add more info to its page and you don't have edit permissions.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Great! Thank you. Are you able to please tag the other HOL [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121473/theorem-proving-from-first-principles-using-sml-with-hol-inference-rules)? (it's an edit of less than 6 characters).

Comment: @tbrk yup, it's been done.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `THEN` tactical applies the second tactic to **all** the subgoals produced by the first tactic ([source](http://hol.sourceforge.net/kananaskis-8-helpdocs/help/Docfiles/HTML/Tactical.THEN.html)). But ``` ACCEPT_TAC (ASSUME ``p:bool``) ``` only applies to the first subgoal. You do not see any problem when you apply the tactics one-by-one because you never try to apply the `ACCEPT_TAC` to the second subgoal. The following solution uses [`THENL`](http://hol.sourceforge.net/kananaskis-8-helpdocs/help/Docfiles/HTML/Tactical.THENL.html) instead of `THEN`.

```
val g1 = (([], ``!(p:bool) (q:bool). (p ==> q) ==> p ==> p /\ q``) : goal);
val absorptionRule =
    TAC_PROOF (g1,
        REPEAT STRIP_TAC
        THENL [ACCEPT_TAC (ASSUME ``p:bool``), RES_TAC]);
```